# Necesito Refrescar una View Al usar onchage en un select. en MVC 4 razor C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc

tengo un problema con el uso de un

```
select class="selection-box large-select" name="drop" id="drop"onchange="rut()">
```

el cual lo estoy utilizando para enviar su valor a un

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult MiPerfil(string pRutIn) 
{
    pFechaIn = "15/06/2014"; 
    var tipo1 = clsMW_SPB_IMF_PFL_CLT.execute(pRutIn, pFechaIn);
    return View(tipo1);            
}
```

para que me pueda cargar una tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego de que se cargue , el combobox me permite seleccionar otro usuario y esta tabla debería de refrescar o la pagina con los datos del usuario nuevo.
he estado intentado trabajar con `AJAX`.

**JavaScript**

```
function rut() {

    debugger;
    var pRutIn = $("#drop").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '~/User/MiPerfil',
        type: 'POST',
        datatyoe: 'JSON',
        data: ({ pRutIn: +pRutIn }),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#drop").html("");
            $.each($.result), function (i, rut) {
                $("#drop").append($('<option></option>').val(drop.ondrop).html(""))
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error en la respuesta")
        }
    });
}
```

Cómo puedo refrescar los datos cada vez que seleccione un usuario en el combobox y también como hacer para que se refresque la página?

**Actualización**

Aún no realiza ningún cambio al seleccionar una opción del select, el código esta así:

```
function SelectionChanged() {

    debugger;
    var pRutIn = $("#drop").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '~/User/MiPerfil',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: ({ "pRutIn": pRutIn }),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#drop").html("");
            $.each($.result), function (i, rut)
            {
                $("#drop").append($('<option></option>').val(drop.ondrop).html("")) **esta parte no se si esta bien...**
                }

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error en la respuesta")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Me parece que hay una confusion de tecnologias y una mezcla de cosas para lo que quieres hacer. Puedes embeber Ajax directamente en la pagina desde C#, para ahorrarte los problemas de escribir tu propio JS. O estas buscando que todo se ejecute del lado del cliente. Si es asi, donde estas pasando los datos de las tablas?

Comment: podrías colocar un ejemplo de la data que regresa "tipo1" ? saludos

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos [Manu Keteimporta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/14556/manu-keteimporta) (curioso nick), por lo que veo, se trata de actualizar solamente esa parte de la página. Para lograrlo en vez de renderizar toda la vista, hazlo con una vista parcial:

```
return PartialView(tipo1)
```

en el lado del cliente, reemplaza lo que tienes en data por esto:

```
data: { "pRutIn": pRutIn },
```

es `dataType` no `datatyoe`.

**Actualización**

y para llamar a la función de manera constante en cada `on change` del `select`:

```
$('#drop').on('change', function() {
   rut();
})
```

**Actualización 2**

Esta parte:

```
$.each($.result), function (i, rut)
                    {
                        $("#drop").append($('<option></option>').val(drop.ondrop).html(""))
                    }
```

Reemplazala por:

```
$.each(result, function (i, rut) {
    $('#drop').append($('<option>', { 
        value: rut.value,
        text : rut.text 
    }));
});
```

Comment: Acabo de realizar lo que me dijiste, sin obtener ningún cambio, la idea es que cuando seleccione un usuario el value valla al action result con el dato y luego me pueda refrescar la pagina con los nuevos datos

Comment: ya te entendí, actualizando respuesta en 3..2...

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias lo probare.

Comment: por cierto, es `dataType` no `datatyoe`

Comment: nos avisas qué tal te fue :D

Comment: @ManuKeteimporta te funcionó?

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: Lo siento soy nuevo acá y no se como generar un post con mis dudas que me han a aparecido en estos momentos, De todas formas gracias.

Comment: normal mi estimado, todos iniciamos así :D te ayudo a editar la pregunta, relax

Comment: por cierto, he actualizado la respuesta, intenta :D